How to import Revit room into a Power BI report? Or create a topojson/geojson file from Revit rooms?
I am attempting to import data from Revit rooms into an interactive Power BI report. I would like to bring the room geometries into the PBI report and link it with external data tables, creating interactive data visualizations. Is this something that's possible to do without paying for a custom PBI visual?
I have looked online and have only seen subscription based add-ons that would accomplish this. I have also tried to follow this video but was not receiving the correct shapes once imported into Power BI
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-y7gwi6wtk&ab_channel=Gioru
I have installed pyrevit but writing something like this from scratch seems to be a big undertaking.

I believe that this open source pyrevit add-on is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/dolanklock/revit-rooms-to-json
You need to install pyrevit and python 3.8 to use it but once set up it is pretty straightforward. The add-on extracts room geometries and properties into geojson or topojson files. Topojson files can be used in a Power BI report through the Shape map visual.
example
